# Is this subset of a unit sphere open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry

Consider the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Let $U = \{x\in \mathbb{S}^2: x_3 < 1/4 \}$. Can I say this $U$ is an open set? The thing is, by definition of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is not. But I think it is an open set in the sense of the subspace topology for $\mathbb{S}^2$. But can I just say $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{S}^2$? The thing is, I know an open subset of a manifold is a manifold, so I wish to conclude that $U$ is in fact a manifold as well.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: $U$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{S}^2$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks Ninad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V = \{x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x_3 < 1/4 \}$. This is an open subset of $\mathbb R^3$ and $U = S^2 \cap V$. Thus $U$ is open in the subspace topology of $S^2$.